# Not able to understand the plotting of 2-Dimensional graph in python matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib, machine-learning, logistic-regression

The data corresponds to 3 rows where the first row is the marks of Exam number one of a particular student and row number two is the marks in Exam number 2 of the student. The third row corresponds to 0 or 1 indicating his probability to enter a particular University.
Here is the code given for plotting the graph which I am not able to understand.

```
# Find Indices of Positive and Negative Examples
pos = y == 1
neg = y == 0

# Plot Examples
pyplot.plot(X[pos, 0], X[pos, 1], 'k*', lw=2, ms=10)
pyplot.plot(X[neg, 0], X[neg, 1], 'ko', mfc='y', ms=8, mec='k', mew=1)
```

The output is the image given below:

[image: 2-Dimensional Plot]

Any help in explaining the code is appreciated.

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: I am not able to understand the code for plotting the 2d graph. Any documentation where I can read through?

Comment: https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.plot.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code consists two different data, put together into one plot. They are all done with 'matplotlib' as you can read [documentation here](https://matplotlib.org/api/pyplot_api.html).

First plot is plotting only positive examples, marked as a star.
`X[pos,0]` is x-axis (first row, only positive examples) and `X[pos,1]` is y-axis (second row, only positive examples).
Rest of the arguments: `k*` means the style will be "stars", `lw` stands for "linewidth" and `ms` for "markersize", how big each start is.

Second plot is the same, only now for the circle which are negative. First two arguments are the same, only with negative examples. `ko` means to represent each dot a circle (hence o). `mfc`, `mec`, `mew` are for choosing the color of the marker.

Comment: So pos and neg are vectors with indices where y== 1 or y==0 respectively?

Comment: yes. `pos` for example return true only for indices with `y==1`, so it filter them for you

Answer (score 0):

Let's understand by example.

Here Y must be matrix which stores 0 and 1 value.

```
[0. 0. 0. 1. ]
```

So when you write below  code

```
pos = y == 1
neg = y == 0
```

Matrix comparison happens, so,

-wherever row is having value 1 marked as True

-Wherever row is having value 0 marked as False

Hence you will get matrix like below

```
pos = [False False False,True]
neg = [ True  True  True False]
```

Hence this line of code

```
 X[pos, 0]--gives 4th row of first column in the matrix X. Because Row 4 is having true.


 X[neg, 0]-- gives 3 rows values, because first 3 rows values of neg matrix are True
```